# How to stop a textview pushing layout off of screen

Tags: android, ios, android-layout

I am building a app and I just need some help with the attached screen shot.

Currently I have 5 Plain `Textfields` with the last 2 being `textMultilines`. I have a `Relativelayout` with a button placed at the bottom for the user to press submit. The problem is when the `textViews` above are filled in, especially the `multiline` ones, it will push the `Relativelayout` and button off the screen.

How can I stop this from happening
[Picture of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVxBl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Either You should  fix the height of multi lines text or you can simply use Scroll View and put all the text view and button in same relative layout

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them Scrollable by adding ScrollView around them.
like

```
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        //all your views here

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```